# Why is my array not returning properly when I call my route?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm calling my route, and I expect my array to return with a bunch of tweets inside of it, but instead I don't get anything of use.

I've tried moving my filteredTweets array outside of the tweets constant, and also tried not having the constant at all. Ive also tried to get rid of the return statement in the constant, all to no avail.

```
app.route('/get-tweets').get((req, res) => {
  const tweets = T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'iowa state since:2018-07-11 #gameday -filter:media -filter:retweets', count: 10 }, function(err, data, res) {
    let filteredTweets = [];
    _.each(data, userObj => {
      filteredTweets.push(userObj);
    })
    return filteredTweets;
  })
  return res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Tweets fetched successfully',
    tweets: tweets
  });
})
```

I'm getting my message returned successfully but not the tweets section.
{"message":"Tweets fetched successfully","tweets":{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}}

Comment: What is "  _ " assigned to here? Are you using lodash?

Comment: @MikeWaldrup correct that's the lodash library

Comment: I see the API reference says the url for the request is "search/tweets.json?q= . . ." and your T.get doesn't include the '.json' part. Have you implemented that or is it the problem?

Comment: `T.get()` is asynchronous. The return in the callback *does not* return to variable `tweets`. Send your json inside the callback

Comment: @MikeWaldrup I'm not sure I'm following, could you explain that in more depth? When I console.log out userObj I am getting data.

Comment: @charlietfl when I return my res.status(200).json()  inside the T.get() I get an error 
return res.status(200).json({
               ^

TypeError: res.status is not a function

Comment: Try just doing `res.json(filteredTweets)`

Comment: @charlietfl res.json(filteredTweets);
        ^

TypeError: res.json is not a function

Comment: Oh..it's because you are using `res` in the `T.get` callback and shadowing the `res` in the route. Don't use same variable name for both

Comment: @charlietfl awesome, that was indeed the issue. If you put that as the answer I'll mark it as the best one. Thanks for the help!